# SSSD is running, but not working

Tags: ldap, sssd, nss

I cross-compiled and installed SSSD on my Linux-based board (ARM architecture).
This is my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` configuration file:

```
[sssd]
domains = LDAP_DOMAIN
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/LDAP_DOMAIN]
id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap

ldap_uri = ldap://<IP-addr-server>
ldap_search_base = dc=lab,dc=local

cache_credentials = true
enumerate = true

# Anonymous bind are not allowed
ldap_default_bind_dn = uid=test,cn=users,cn=accounts,dc=lab,dc=local
ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = mypassword

ldap_id_use_start_tls = true
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_tls_cacert = /home/ca/ca.crt
```

I start sssd with the following command, giving a path in which to save logs:

```
sssd start -c /etc/sssd/sssd.conf -d=0x1310 --logger=files
```

No errors appears, and SSSD seems to run correctly

```
ps -A | grep SSSD
```

gives:

```
1735 root      0:00 sssd start -c /etc/sssd/sssd.conf -d=0x2000 --logger=files
 1741 root      0:01 /usr/local/libexec/sssd/sssd_be --domain LDAP_DOMAIN --uid 0 --gid 0 -d 0x02000 --logger=files
 1742 root      0:00 /usr/local/libexec/sssd/sssd_nss --uid 0 --gid 0 -d 0x02000 --logger=files
 1743 root      0:00 /usr/local/libexec/sssd/sssd_pam --uid 0 --gid 0 -d 0x02000 --logger=files
```

But I am not able to lookup and authenticate to users on the LDAP server.
I also added sss entry in the `/etc/nsswitch` file.
Am I missing something in the configuration?
Looking at the log files, I cannot see any relevant error messages.
Thanks.

Comment: are you hosting LDAP_DOMAIN on this serer ? if not, did you join the domain ? like `realm join LDAP_DOMAIN -U $user --computer-ou=...`

Comment: unfortunately I am on an embedded device where realm is not installed. But I tryed realm -v discover <server-ip-address> on onother Ubuntu machine, with the same SSSD configuration file, and it gives "successfully discovered lab.local"